# Writing a vector of strings to a string

Tags: r, string, vector, batch-processing

I have a vector of strings:

```
seasons <- c("S200304","S200506","S200708")
```

I have a script that should write a string to a series of new .R script files, then run each of those generated .R files.

```
for (i in 1:length(seasons)){

    ### Generate a string to write to each .R file
    str <- paste0("
        seasons <- c(",toString(seasons),")
        season <- seasons[",i,"]

        source('./a_separate_script_to_get_results.R')

        save(results,file=paste(season,\"output.rda\",sep=\"_\"))
    ")

    ### Write each .R file
    write(str, file=paste0("run_",i,".R"))

    ### Run all .R files
    system(paste0("Rscript run_",i,".R"),wait = F)

}
```

This script should generate three .R files named *run_1.R*, *run_2.R* and *run_3.R*, all of which should be then run concurrently to output three results files named *S200304_output.rda*, *S200506_output.rda* and *S200708_output.rda* respectively.

However, the command to write the *seasons* vector doesn't write the objects as strings, hence second line cannot assign *season* to the first element of *seasons* and the rest fails. The new .R files are generated but not run, because *seasons* is written in each file as

```
seasons <- c(S200304,S200506,S200708)
```

The *seasons* vector does need to be written in each .R file, so how can I write this vector of strings to a string, please? I have used this code before but the initial *seasons* vector was not populated with strings, so it ran without any problems. Defining *seasons* explicitly won't work as *seasons* is generated by earlier code.

Comment: Maybe try `paste0("'",paste(seasons,collapse = "','"),"'")` instead?

Comment: joran, I think that's got it! Thank you very much. An elegant solution.